# Error in line (strRadius = input.readLine(); Have done everything i know to do, I'm a very new Java coder

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

```
/*
Programmer://deleted for privacy
Date: 1/19/2015
Program Name:   CircumferenceDebug.java
*/ 
import java.io.*;

public class CircumferenceDebug  {
   public static void main(String[] args) { 

   BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new 
   InputStreamReader(System.in));

   String strRadius;
   int radius;
   double pi = Math.PI;
   double answer;

   System.out.print("Enter a radius? ");
   strRadius = input.readLine();  
      radius = Integer.parseInt(strRadius);

   answer = pi*(double)radius*2;
   System.out.println("The circumference of the circle is "+  
    Math.round(answer));

   System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that you are trying to call a function on a variable that does not exist. In your code, where you want to read a user's input, you call `readLine()` on the variable `input()`. My guess is that this was copy/pasted from another source somewhere. But, when you defined your `BufferedReader`, you gave it the variable name `dataIn`.

You have 2 options, the first being to change the variable name of `dataIn`:

```
BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

to:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Or, you can change the variable referenced at your user input from:

```
input.readLine();
```

to:

```
dataIn.readLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mike.  I understand now what I was doing wrong.... I read back through the code and saw what you were saying that I needed to do.  Your knowledge is immeasurable!!!